# Multiple section breaks per page in MS Word causing page numbers to repeat

Tags: microsoft-word, page-numbers, footers

I have a Word document with numerous section breaks throughout. Because *some* of my content is arranged in two columns (with a variety of tables and figures in one column), many of the section breaks are continuous and appear on the same page.

I added page numbers in the footer and checked "Continue from previous section" on every page. However, for pages with more than one (continuous) section break on a preceding page, the page numbers restart at 1 or repeat.

Looking at the footer, I can see that the section number (labeling the footer) skips ahead (e.g., from -Section 11- to -Section 13-). I've tried selecting text in the section, opening "Format Page Numbers," and making sure "Continue from previous section" is still selected. That's made no difference.

The document is long, and content is under constant revision. Handcoding the page numbers is my last resort. Has anyone found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Please add some screenshots as the explanation is not enough to identify the exact trouble.

Comment: A download file that demonstrates the problem would be even better.

Comment: The document is not something I'm able to share publicly, unfortunately. Not yet at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a very similar issue not too long ago and came across this Microsoft forum post:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/page-numbering-off-when-using-continuous-section/51c65293-25e4-4660-a5f9-ee2c08a70dca

In that post, Stefan Blom posted the following macro that once entered and run solved the page numbering issue:

```
Sub SetContinuousPageNumbering()
Dim s As Section
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Sections
s.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
.PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
Next s
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh my Word, you're a life saver! It worked! Bless you!!!

Comment: I beat my head against a wall for days dealing with the same thing.  So glad I could help,