# Page number confusion

Tags: microsoft-word

I added a simple page number in the footer of a doc. I am having trouble with page 5. If I open the footer it shows "5" but when I switch back to the body of the page it shows "2". I have selected "Continue from previous section" in the Page Number Format dialog box.

I do have multiple sections (several page breaks, portions with 2 columns) but this problem only occurs twice in the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous section breaks (like the ones you use to switch between single and double columns and back) tend to cause these kinds of issues (in my personal experience anyway).

I posted an answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1547378/multiple-section-breaks-per-page-in-ms-word-causing-page-numbers-to-repeat/1548215#1548215); the problem was similar and maybe it will help you as well. I'll re-post it here as well:

---

I ran into a very similar issue not too long ago and came across this Microsoft forum post: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother/page-numbering-off-when-using-continuous-section/51c65293-25e4-4660-a5f9-ee2c08a70dca

In that post, Stefan Blom posted the following macro that once entered and run solved the page numbering issue:

```
Sub SetContinuousPageNumbering()
Dim s As Section
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Sections
s.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
.PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
Next s
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.